# Topology, maps, continuity

Tags: general-topology

[image]

I know how to write all the maps, however, how would i find out which of those are continuous.

Comment: Continuity of $f:X\to Y$ is whenever $U \subseteq Y$ is open then $f^{-1}(U) \subseteq X$ is open.

Comment: what if $U \subseteq Y$ is closed?

Comment: @smits - then $f^{-1}(U)$ is closed. This condition is equivalent for the continuity of $f$

Comment: @Belgi so for example when I'm mapping $X$ to $Y$, if i map $a,b$ to $2,3$ it would be open? but if i map $a,b$ to $1,3$ it would be closed?

Comment: @smith In your last comment it's not clear where you're sending each element.  Do you recall that a subset is open if it's in the topology?

Comment: sorry i was sending them in order i.e for the first example i was sending $a$ to $2$ and $b$ to $3$... yes i recall that subsets are open if they're in the topology, therefore in the second example $\{1,3\}$ is not in the topology so its closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to use the following characterization for continuity:

> $f : X \to Y$ is continuous iff for all $U$ open in $Y$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

Let's consider the first set of maps you mentioned $f : X \to X$. (Once you see this, the rest should be easy to figure out, although perhaps tedious.)

1. $a \mapsto a$, $b \mapsto b$. This is the identity map, so it's obviously continuous. (Exercise: Prove that the identity map on any topological space is always continuous)
2. $a \mapsto a$, $b \mapsto a$. This is continuous because $f^{-1}(\emptyset) = \emptyset$, $f^{-1}(X) = \{a\}$ and $f^{-1}(\{a\}) = \{a\}$ (that is, the inverse image of each open set is open).
3. $a \mapsto b$, $b \mapsto a$. This is **not** continuous as $f^{-1}(\{a\}) = \{b\}$ which is not open.
4. $a \mapsto b$, $b \mapsto b$. This is **not** open as $f^{-1}(X) = \{b\}$ which is not open.